# Convert `this.page` inside a `useEffect` Hook? Getting error on `this.` saying `Object is possibly undefined` while configuring Disqus in React + TS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am trying to create a `useDisqus` hook that looks like:

```
import React from 'react'

import { siteMetadata } from '@/_data/index'

const config = siteMetadata.comment.disqus

const SHORTNAME = config.shortname as string

export const useDisqus = (commentNodeId: string, slug: string) => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const scriptParentNode = document.getElementById(commentNodeId)
        if (!scriptParentNode) return
        
        ;(window as any).disqus_config.page.url = window.location.href
        ;(window as any).disqus_config.page.identifier = slug // how to write this??

        if ((window as any).DISQUS === undefined) {
            const script = document.createElement('script')
            const attributes = {
                src: `https://${SHORTNAME}disqus.com/embed.js`,
                'data-timestamp': `${+new Date()}`,
                crossorigin: 'anonymous',
                async: 'true',
            }

            Object.entries(attributes).forEach(([name, value]) => script.setAttribute(name, value))

            scriptParentNode.appendChild(script)
        } else {
            ;(window as any).DISQUS.reset({ reload: true })
        }
    }, [commentNodeId, slug])
}
```

The full working component with `Load Comments` button that I got from another repository looks like:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import siteMetadata from '@/data/siteMetadata'

const Disqus = ({ frontMatter }) => {
  const [enableLoadComments, setEnabledLoadComments] = useState(true)

  const COMMENTS_ID = 'disqus_thread'

  function LoadComments() {
    setEnabledLoadComments(false)

    window.disqus_config = function () {
      this.page.url = window.location.href
      this.page.identifier = frontMatter.slug
    }
    if (window.DISQUS === undefined) {
      const script = document.createElement('script')
      script.src = 'https://' + siteMetadata.comment.disqus.shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js'
      script.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date())
      script.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous')
      script.async = true
      document.body.appendChild(script)
    } else {
      window.DISQUS.reset({ reload: true })
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="pt-6 pb-6 text-center text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300">
      {enableLoadComments && <button onClick={LoadComments}>Load Comments</button>}
      <div className="disqus-frame" id={COMMENTS_ID} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Disqus
```

Notice, this part:

```
window.disqus_config = function () {
    this.page.url = window.location.href
    this.page.identifier = frontMatter.slug
}
```

Idk how to convert it into `useDisqus` hook as `this.` is `undefined` in a Stateless component.

How do I convert that part? I've currently written it as the following but it doesn't work:

```
;(window as any).disqus_config.page.url = window.location.href
;(window as any).disqus_config.page.identifier = slug // how to write this??
```

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at [the docs](https://help.disqus.com/en/articles/1717084-javascript-configuration-variables), it seems like `window.disqus_config` is meant to be a **function** that sets some variables.  The `this` inside the body of the function refers to the `this` context of the function itself rather than the component.

As a TypeScript issue, you can declare the `this` type for the function.  You know that it should be something with a `page` object.  Try this:

```
;(window as any).disqus_config = function(this: {page: Record<string, string>}) {
    this.page.url = window.location.href
    this.page.identifier = slug
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems right but I'm getting CORS error as I'm trying it on my localhost so I would accept & upvote this answer as soon as I publish the website. This was exactly what I wanted. I knew it was a funcition but didn't knew how to write it in TS so I went with some stupid stuff haha :)